# REST connections using Qorus

Tags: rest

is there a way to specify the protocol (HTTPor HTTPS) used for REST connections in Qorus integration engine? 
I tried to check the connection files which defines the rest URLs, but seems that I couldnt find a way to specify the protocol.

In my case I need to connect via HTTPS but currently the connection is failing because it tries with connect via HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When specifying your connection you need to provide `url`.  I assume you used `rest` scheme there but you need to use `rests` in order to activate HTTPS (e.g. `rests://user:pass@example.com:8080/path`).

Btw, the full details can be found in the official [Qorus documentation](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus/current/qorus/connmon.html#userconn_rest).